# Android SIP sample project SipDemo: No audio for outgoing calls

Tags: android, audio, sip

When I call the SIP number thats configured on the SipDemo, and when i am running on my mobile phone, everything works perfectly. But when I use SipDemo to call the SIP number of my simulator, it rings, the call is established, Asterisk logs indicate everything is fine and the calls are bridged but there is no audio at all on both sides!

Do you have any idea of what might be going on?

Thanks a lot!